# Industrial Handheld Terminals with Android?

Tags: android, webkit, windows-mobile

Are there any industrial handheld terminals (e.g. from honeywell or datalogic) which are shipped with Android?

It seems to me, that all of them are Windows CE/Mobile only, which sucks (beginning at the browser).

We've created a webbased-App for the DataLogic Memor, but the industrial browser on it doesn't even come close to a Webkit-Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally there are some industrial handhelds **with** barcode scanner

[Bluebird - Pidion BIP-6000Max - Android Rugged Handheld Computer](http://mypidion.com/product/product_tab4.asp?t_idx=41&bmenu=1)

[Bluebird - Pidion BM-170 - Android Handheld PDA](http://mypidion.com/product/product_tab4.asp?t_idx=40&bmenu=1)

Answer (score 0):

There is the Motorola i1. Psion was planning to release one in Q3 2010, but I don't know if they did.

Comment: it should have a real barcode scanner

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this and as the link in the accepted answer above isn't working anymore, here's the only Android terminal I've found:

[Dolphin 7800 for Android](http://www.honeywellaidc.com/en-us/pages/Product.aspx?category=Enterprise%20Digital%20Assistant%20%28EDA%29&cat=HSM&pid=Dolphin7800A) - they already have a User Manual!